# How to find out which functions were NOT inlined

Tags: c++, c, gcc, inline

Is there a way to obtain a list of functions that were NOT inlined anywhere? Either by passing an option to gcc or by inspecting the binary?

EDIT: I know how to explicitly ask for a function not to be inlined by using gcc's builtin attribute noinline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use gcc's `-fdump-tree-all` and search the dump files for "inline".

Answer (score 7):

Add `-fdump-ipa-inline` to your compiler options.

Grep the file `yoursourcefile.inline` which is created next to the object file for "Considering inline candidate" to find out all functions that the compiler *considered* inlining.

Grep the file for "Inlined into" to find out all functions that the compiler finally *did inline*.
Grep for "inline_failed:" if you are interested for the reason why the compiler turned down a candidate (e.g. "call is unlikely and code size would grow").

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[nm command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nm_%28Unix%29)** in Unix/Linux to get list of symbols in a binary.
If the function is not inlined its symbol name will be present in the binary.

Comment: That's not correct. Non-static functions will be emitted regardless of whether they were inlined or not.

Comment: @Mat, no. The inlining model for C++ is probably a bit more complicated, but for C (C99 and C11) a symbol is only emitted in a translation unit that has requests an "instantiantion" of the symbol, i.e for C that has an inline *definition* and an external declaration.

Comment: @Als, +1, but you could perhaps be a bit more precise. A symbol name can be present as an undefined symbol or for defining the symbol. Whether or not it defines the symbol depends much on the instantiation models, I think they may be quite different in different C++ implementation (my knowledge about C++ here is a bit rusty) and in C.

Comment: @JensGustedt: any cursory test invalidates your first comment (with GCC anyway). Since when did the C standard dictate what goes into the compiler's intermediate outputs and what doesn't anyway?

Comment: A C compiler can inline any function it likes if it makes the program go faster, but it can only completely delete the stand-alone function if it's not exported to other files - the compiler can't know that nothing else will call it unless it's declared static. So, @Mat is correct.

Comment: @Mat "Since when did the C standard dictate what goes into the compiler's intermediate outputs and what doesn't anyway?" since C99, the point where the `inline` keyword made it into C. For `gcc` without `-std=c99` the implementation of `inline` is an extension to C89, and in fact their model for inlining is different from the one in the standard.

Comment: @ams, no he is not. C99 prescibes that a function that is marked `inline` must not produce a symbol unless there is also an external declaration. I wrote the rules up some day, please have a look at http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/11/29/myth-and-reality-about-inline-in-c99/

Comment: @JensGustedt: who said anything about functions marked `inline`?

Comment: @JensGustedt: Historically GCC has not been standards compliant in this situation. Basically this is because GCC did inline functions as an extension before they were standardized, and did them differently. I think you had to say `static inline` to get what you say. This may have changed now - I don't know - and probably doesn't apply with `--std=c99`, but you need to be careful.

Answer (score 0):

'inline' is NOT an attribute of a function, a function can be both inlined and non-inlined. when you call a function, the compiler decide whether inline it or not, if there are multiple calls, the compiler may choose different option for different call. if there is at least one non-inlined call, the function will be appear in the symbol table. and if it is exported it will also appear in the symbol table.

so there is no way to check a function is inlined or not, you can only check a specific call is inlined or not by reverse engineer.

Comment: I understand inline is "per call", my question is how to find out if ALL calls are not inlined.

Comment: You just don't answer the question.