# GNU as, puts works but printf does not

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, gnu-assembler, crt

This is the code I am playing with right now:

```
# file-name: test.s
# 64-bit GNU as source code.
    .global main

    .section .text
main:
    lea message, %rdi
    push %rdi
    call puts

    lea message, %rdi
    push %rdi
    call printf

    push $0
    call _exit

    .section .data
message: .asciz "Hello, World!"
```

> Compilation instructions: gcc test.s -o test

Revision 1:

```
    .global main
    .section .text
main:
    lea message, %rdi
    call puts

    lea message, %rdi
    call printf

    mov $0, %rdi
    call _exit

    .section .data
message: .asciz "Hello, World!"
```

Final Revision (Works):

```
    .global main
    .section .text
main:
    lea message, %rdi
    call puts

    mov $0, %rax
    lea message, %rdi
    call printf

    # flush stdout buffer.
    mov $0, %rdi
    call fflush

    # put newline to offset PS1 prompt when the program ends.  
    # - ironically, doing this makes the flush above redundant and can be removed.
    # - The call to  fflush is retained for display and 
    #      to keep the block self contained.  
    mov $'\n', %rdi
    call putchar

    mov $0, %rdi
    call _exit

    .section .data
message: .asciz "Hello, World!"
```

I am struggling to understand why the call to puts succeeds but the call to printf results in a Segmentation fault.

Can somebody explain this behavior and how printf is intended to be called?

Thanks ahead of time.

---

**Summary**:

1. printf obtains the printing string from %rdi and the number of additional arguments in %rax's lower DWORD.
2. printf results cannot be seen until a newline is put into stdout, or fflush(0) is called.

Comment: If you're on Linux then when calling `printf` (and other functions that take a variable number of arguments) you need to load AL with the number of arguments you're passing in XMM registers. In this case the number would be 0.

Comment: what is the AL register on 64 bit system?

Comment: It's the lower 8-bits of the RAX register. You can refer to it by `%al`, eg. `mov $0, %al` though `xor %eax,%eax` is probably preferable in this case.

Comment: I figured it out, I was a bit confused by passing 0 to %rax felt nothing happened but, but I remembered that I should have tried flushing it after printing. Updated OP with current solution.

Comment: I updated my answer with some improvements and comments on your final version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`puts` appends a newline implicitly, and stdout is line-buffered (by default on terminals).  So the text from `printf` may just be sitting there in the buffer.  Your [call to `_exit(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/_exit.2.html) doesn't flush buffers, because it's the [`exit_group(2)` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/exit_group.2.html), not the [`exit(3)` library function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html).  (See my version of your code below).

Your call to `printf(3)` is also not quite right, because you didn't zero `%al` before calling a var-args function with no FP arguments.  (Good catch @RossRidge, I missed that).  [`xor %eax,%eax` is the best way to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/which-is-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and).  `%al` will be non-zero (from `puts()`'s return value), which is presumably why printf segfaults.  I tested on my system, and printf doesn't seem to mind when the stack is misaligned (which it is, since you pushed twice before calling it, unlike puts).

(Update: newer builds of glibc *will* segfault in printf with misaligned RSP even with AL=0, since gcc makes more use of SSE to load or store 16 bytes at a time, and of course takes advantage of the ABI-guaranteed alignment.  See [an example from scanf and how to avoid it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070716/glibc-scanf-segmentation-faults-when-called-from-a-function-that-doesnt-align-r))

---

Also, you don't need any `push` instructions in that code.  The first arg goes in `%rdi`.  The first 6 integer args go in registers, the 7th and later go on the stack.  You're also neglecting to pop the stack after the functions return, which only works because your function never tries to return after messing up the stack.

The ABI does require aligning the stack by 16B, and a `push` is one way to do that, which can actually be more efficient than `sub $8, %rsp` on recent Intel CPUs with a stack engine, and it takes fewer bytes.  (See [the x86-64 SysV ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf), and other links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki).

---

Improved code:

```
.text
.global main
main:
    lea     message(%rip), %rdi     # or  mov $message, %edi  if you don't need the code to be position-independent: default code model has all labels in the low 2G, so you can use shorter 32bit instructions
    push    %rbx              # align the stack for another call
    mov     %rdi, %rbx        # save for later
    call   puts

    xor     %eax,%eax         # %al = 0 = number of FP args for var-args functions
    mov     %rbx, %rdi        # or mov %ebx, %edi  in a non-PIE executable, since the pointer is known to be pointing to static storage which will be in the low 2GiB
    call   printf

    # optionally putchar a '\n', or include it in the string you pass to printf

    #xor    %edi,%edi    # exit with 0 status
    #call  exit          # exit(3) does an fflush and other cleanup

    pop     %rbx         # restore caller's rbx, and restore the stack

    xor     %eax,%eax    # return 0 from main is equivalent to exit(0)
    ret

    .section .rodata     # constants should go in .rodata
message: .asciz "Hello, World!"
```

`lea message(%rip), %rdi` is cheap, and doing it twice is fewer instructions than the two `mov` instructions to make use of `%rbx`.  But since we needed to adjust the stack by 8B to strictly follow the ABI's 16B-aligned guarantee, we might as well do it by saving a call-preserved register.  `mov reg,reg` is very cheap and small, so taking advantage of the call-preserved reg is natural.

Modern distros now default to making PIE executables so pointers are 64-bit even for static storage.  You need RIP-relative LEA, and need 64-bit operand-size to copy them.  See *[How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212012/how-to-load-address-of-function-or-label-into-register)* for that vs. `mov $message, %edi` in a non-PIE.  There's never a reason to use `lea message, %rdi` with a 32-bit absolute addressing mode, only ever RIP-relative LEA or mov-immediate.

Comment: by the way, why is xor used in this example? I see it used often but can't make sense of the reasoning behind it. Is it cheaper?

Comment: @Dmitry: I already made a change to the text which added a link about xor.

Comment: My bad. I'll memorize this idiom. Although now i'm tempted to replace all of my 0 assignments in C with ^=... I'm not sure how good of an idea that is. Thanks for the solution, it's a lot to take in. I'll take some time studying it.

Comment: @Dmitry: that's a terrible idea in C.  It's optimal on x86, not in general.  On most architectures, `reg = reg^reg` will have a false dependency on the old value.  It makes your code less readable, and there's no way to do it without having the C source use the uninitialized value.  ([Compilers don't like that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32408665/fastest-absolute-value-calculator-using-sse/32422471#comment53135971_32422471).   note the typo in that comment, though: it should be `_mm_undefined_si128()`, not `_mm_uninitialized_si128()`.)

Comment: Anyway, it's just horrible for human-readability as well.  It's the standard idiom in x86, not in C.  **Compilers know about this and will do it correctly**.  They will always emit `xor same,same` instead of `mov $0, %reg`, except at `-O0` when they don't check for that peephole optimization.

Comment: still an interesting thing to understand. I like being able to read back what compiler produces and understand its' optimizations, or lacks of.

Comment: @Dmitry: yes, for sure.  You can learn a lot from understanding compiler output from fairly simple functions.  It's a mistake to turn around and apply some of the techniques to the C source, though.  In this case, one of the many facets of that mistake is that it's only how x86 does things, not optimal on e.g. ARM or MIPS.  (on MIPS, you zero `r3` with `addiu r3, r0, #0`: add immediate-zero to the architectural zero-register, and store the result in `r3`.  There is no `move` insn, just a pseudo-op mnemonic for it.  It would be similarly silly to write `a = b+0` instead of `a = b` in C, though)

Comment: @Dmitry: Actually it's not quite true that you shouldn't apply what you learn to C.  You can sometimes change the C to make it easier / possible for the compiler to use arch-specific peephole optimizations like `LEA`.  More generally, though, you can structure code in ways that will work well in asm.  If you know an input can't be zero, then you can use a `do { } while()` loop instead of a `while()` loop, so the compiler doesn't have to check to make sure the loop runs at least once.  Hoisting loop invariants can help, and so can manual unrolling with manual intro/epilogue for odd numbers.

Comment: One more question: how do I call printf("%u", a_number_in_data_section); in assembly? I can't manage to do it, I seem to be misunderstanding the role of %eax here.

Comment: ok I looked at compiler output and found that rax was still 0 for the printf with 2 arguments(I thought I needed to pass 1). All I had to do was pass the string as rdi, the second argument as rsi, 0 as rax, and call printf.

Thanks!

Comment: @Dmitry: yup.  `%al` is the number of floating point args (passed in xmm registers) to a var-args function.  Still zero since pointers and unsigned int are both integer args.

Comment: @Bulat: Try your edit again, I noticed a couple things after coming to see how this answer was doing after getting the upvote notification, and my edit overwrote yours.

Comment: @PeterCordes Comments say that's changing `mov %rbx, %rdi` to `mov %ebx, %edi` without breaking seem to be false. Also, code doesn't compile on line `lea     message, %rdi`. Needs to be changed to `lea     message(%rip), %rdi` when compiling with *gcc*.

Comment: @mathway: PIE executables are now the default in most Linux distros.  Updated this old answer to change my obsolete recommendations; thanks.