# Best way to find minimal difference between two values in a cyclic system?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance

Take for example time:

If we take a 12-hour clock, we'd get the following results

- from 1 to 5 = 4
- from 5 to 1 = 4
- from 11 to 1 = 2
- from 1 to 11 = 2

What is the most efficient way to do that?

Assuming the values are doubles.

Comment: what did you try? There 2 possible answers, pick the lower one... whats the problem?

Comment: This thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878907/the-smallest-difference-between-2-angles

Comment: `min((12+a-b)%12,(12-a+b)%12)`

Comment: From 5 to 1 = 4. Can you elaborate this?

Answer (score 2):

Without using modulo operations. `fabs` is cheap.

```
double closest_dist_in_cycle(double a, double b, double cycle){
    double result = std::fabs(a - b);
    return std::min(result, cycle - result);
}
```

**Reference:**

[How would fabs(double) be implemented on x86? Is it an expensive operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630015/how-would-fabsdouble-be-implemented-on-x86-is-it-an-expensive-operation/44718014#44718014)

Answer (score 0):

With `mod` being your cycle, and under the assumption that both input values are smaller than `mod`, you can use:

```
int x = std::min((mod + a - b) % mod, (mod - a + b) % mod);
```

Comment: Well, I just noticed the requirement `Assuming the values are doubles`, which of course makes this solution irrelevant, since the modulo operator `%` is defined only for integers. Not sure how exactly a cyclic system would be defined over non-integers though...

Comment: OP wants `a` and `b` `doubles`

Comment: @idclev463035818: Yeah I just noticed that, see my comment above.

Comment: yeah posted almost the same second. Its only a small change. `fmod` in place of `%`

Comment: Hope to see a more efficient way

Comment: @Hrisip why do you think it needs to be more efficient? Whats not effcicient enough about this?

Comment: @idclev463035818, this solution involves branching and two modulo operations, that's quite expensive for what seems to be a simple task.