# How to input and output real numbers in assembly language

Tags: assembly, io, floating-point, fpu, real-number

We solve problems with real numbers in assembly language using FPU. Usually we write input and output code using C language or ready functions.For example:

```
    ; Receiving input and output descriptors for the console
    invoke  GetStdHandle,   STD_INPUT_HANDLE
    mov     hConsoleInput,  eax

    invoke  GetStdHandle,   STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    mov     hConsoleOutput, eax

    invoke  ClearScreen
    ;input X
    invoke  WriteConsole, hConsoleOutput, ADDR aszPromptX,\
            LENGTHOF aszPromptX - 1, ADDR BufLen, NULL
    invoke  ReadConsole, hConsoleInput, ADDR Buffer,\
            LENGTHOF Buffer, ADDR BufLen, NULL
    finit
    invoke  StrToFloat, ADDR Buffer, ADDR X
```

How to do input and output of real numbers in assembly language without using ready functions?

Comment: Is this a homework question? [We have an etiquette about those](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: It's "too broad" as is. What particular problem are you having? Can you do it for integers? Note you can just scale by the appropriate power of 10 to get your float, after sorting out some parsing issues.

Comment: What do you really want to do? A complete solution for printing correctly rounded floating-point numbers is not easy, even in higher-level languages. If you just want to print numbers in a restricted domain for a particular situation, there may be easier solutions, such as printing a few digits with a fixed precision.

Comment: Updated my answer, I forgot that the integer part of a `float` or `double` might not fit in a 64-bit integer, so you potentially need multiple steps to handle the largest FP values, even without considering the fractional part.  (And working from the largest digit first isn't safe because of rounding.)

Answer (score 4):

**This is really the same question as how to implement those functions / how they work under the hood**.  I'm just going to talk about input in this answer; I'm not sure what algorithms are good for float->string.

OS-provided functions let you read / write (print) characters, one at a time or in blocks.  The interesting / FP-specific part of the problem is only the float->string and string->float part.  Everything else is the same as for reading/printing integers (modulo calling-convention differences: floats are usually returned in FP registers).

---

Correctly implementing [`strtod` (string to double)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) and the single-precision equivalent is highly non-trivial if you want the result to always be correctly rounded to the nearest representable FP value, especially if you want it to also be efficient, and work for inputs right up to the limits of the biggest finite values that `double` can hold.

Once you know the details of the algorithm (in terms of looking at single digits and doing FP multiplies / divides / additions, or integer operations on the FP bit-pattern), you can of implement it in asm for any platform you like.  You used an x87 `finit` instruction in your example for some reason.

**See http://www.exploringbinary.com/how-glibc-strtod-works/ for a detailed look at glibc's implementation, and http://www.exploringbinary.com/how-strtod-works-and-sometimes-doesnt/ for another widely-used implmentation.**

Outlining the first article, glibc's `strtod` uses extended-precision *integer* arithmetic.  It parses the input decimal string to determine the integer part and the fractional part.  e.g. `456.833e2` (scientific notation) has an integer part of `45683` and a fractional part `0.3`.

It converts both parts to floating point separately.  The integer part is easy, because there's already hardware support for converting integers to floating point.  e.g. x87 `fild` or SSE2 `cvtsi2sd`, or whatever else on other architectures.  But if the integer part is larger than the maximum 64-bit integer, it's not that simple, and you need to convert BigInteger to float/double, which hardware doesn't support.

Note that even `FLT_MAX` (single precision) for IEEE binary32 `float` is [`(2 − 2^−23) × 2^127`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), which is just *slightly* below 2^128, so you could use a 128-bit integer for string->`float`, and if that wraps then the correct `float` result is `+Infinity`.  The `FLT_MAX` [bit pattern is `0x7f7fffff`](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html): mantissa all-ones = 1.999... with max exponent.  In decimal, it's `~3.4 × 10^38`.

But if you didn't care about efficiency, I think you could convert each digit to a `float` (or index an array of already-converted `float` values), and do the usual `total = total*10 + digit`, or in this case `total = total*10.0 + digit_values[digit]`.  FP mul / add is exact for integers up to the point where two adjacent representable values are farther apart than 1.0 (i.e. when `nextafter(total, +Infinity)` is `total+2.0`), i.e. when 1 ulp is greater than `1.0`.

Actually, to get correct rounding you need to add the small values *first*, otherwise they each separately round down when all together they could have bumped a large value up to the next representable value.

So you can probably use the FPU for this if you do it carefully, like working in chunks of 8 digits and scaling by 10^8 or something, and add starting with the smallest.  You could convert each string of 8 digits to integer and use hardware `int`->`float`.

---

**The fractional part is even trickier**, especially if you want to avoid repeated division by 10 to get the place values, which you should avoid because it's slow and because `1/10` is not exactly representable in binary floating point so all your place values will have rounding error if you do it the "obvious" way.

But if the integer part is very large, all 53 mantissa bits of the `double` might already be determined by the integer part.  So glibc checks, and only does big-integer division to get the number of bits it needs (if any) from the fractional part.

Anyway, I highly recommend reading both articles.

---

BTW, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format if you're not familiar the bit patterns that IEEE754 binary64, aka `double`, uses to represent numbers.  You don't *need* to be to write a simplistic implementation, but it does help to understand float.  And with x86 SSE, you need to know where the sign bit is to implement absolute value (ANDPS) or negation (XORPS).  [Fastest way to compute absolute value using SSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32408665/fastest-way-to-compute-absolute-value-using-sse/32422471#32422471).  There aren't special instructions for `abs` or `neg`, you just use boolean ops to manipulate the sign bit.  (Much more efficient than subtracting from zero.)

---

If you don't care about being accurate to the last ULP (unit in the last place = lowest bit of the mantissa), then you can do a simpler algorithm of multiplying by 10 and adding like for string -> integer, and then scale by a power of 10 at the end.

But a robust library function can't do that, because **creating a temporary value many times larger than the final result means it will overflow (to `+/- Infinity`) for some inputs that are within the range that `double` can represent**.  Or possibly underflow to `+/- 0.0` if you create smaller temporary values.

Handling the integer and fractional part separately avoids the overflow problem.

See [this C implementation on codereview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44869/implement-strtod-parsing) for an example of a very simple multiply/add approach that will probably overflow.  I only skimmed it quickly, but I don't see it splitting integer/fractional part.  It only handles scientific notation `E99` or whatever at the end, with repeated multiply or divide by 10.