# Floating point compare of absolute values in AVX

Tags: performance, x86, floating-point, simd, avx

I would like to compare two vectors of doubles based on their *absolute values*.

That is, the vector equivalent of the following:

```cpp
if (fabs(x) < fabs(y)) {
    ...
}
```

Is there anything better than just taking the [absolute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32408665/fastest-way-to-compute-absolute-value-using-sse) of each side and following up with a `_mm256_cmp_pd`?

Interested in all of AVX, AVX2, and AVX-512 flavors.

Comment: Probably the following idea works for AVX-512, but I don't have the hardware to figure out the details: Maybe you can use `y_sgnx=_mm512_mask_ternarylogic_epi64(x,y,z,c8)`, with `z=_mm512_set1_epi64(0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFull)`, and a `c8` such that `y_sgnx` is the same as `y`, but with the sign bit of `x`. Cast `x` and `y_sgnx` from double to `epi64` (`_mm512_castpd_si512`). Now you can use an unsigned integer compare with `x` and `y_sgnx` (`_mm512_cmp_epu64_mask`) to get the right mask. See also [here](http://0x80.pl/articles/avx512-ternary-functions.html#bit-select-function-update)

Comment: Another `ternarylogic` idea would be to integer-subtract `x` from `y` then check if the result sign bit equals the sign of `x ^ y`

Comment: Do you have *any* reason to expect the [obvious](https://godbolt.org/z/TzMxPK) `vandpd; vandpd; vcmpltpd` to be limiting your performance?

Comment: @EOF no, I don't.

Answer (score 4):

With AVX-512 you can save one µop. Instead of 2x`vandpd`+`vcmppd` you can use
`vpternlogq`+`vpcmpuq`. Note that the solution below assumes that the numbers are
not a `NaN`.

IEEE-754 floating point numbers have the nice property that they are encoded
such that if `x[62:0]` *integer_less_than* `y[62:0]`, then as a floating point:
`abs(x)<abs(y)`.

So, instead of setting both sign bits to `0`, we can copy the sign bit of `x`
to the sign bit of `y` and compare the result as an unsigned integer.
In the (untested) code below, for negative `x` both `xi[63]` and `yi_sgnx[63]` are `1`,
while for positive `x`, both `xi[63]` and `yi_sgnx[63]` are `0`.
So the unsigned integer compare actually compares `xi[62:0]` with `yi[62:0]`, which is just what we need for the comparison `abs(x)<abs(y)`.

The `vpternlog` instruction is suitable for copying the sign bit, see [here](http://0x80.pl/articles/avx512-ternary-functions.html#bit-select-function-update) or [here](https://www.chessprogramming.org/AVX-512#VPTERNLOG).
I'm not sure if the constants `z` and `0xCA` are chosen correctly.

```c
__mmask8 cmplt_via_ternlog(__m512d x, __m512d y){
    __m512i xi        = _mm512_castpd_si512(x);                                       
    __m512i yi        = _mm512_castpd_si512(x);                                       
    __m512i z         = _mm512_set1_epi64(0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFull);
    __m512i yi_sgnx   = _mm512_ternarylogic_epi64(z, yi, xi, 0xCA);
    return _mm512_cmp_epu64_mask(xi, yi_sgnx, 1);   /* _CMPINT_LT  */
}
```