# why didn't gcc decide inline-or-not for me for this function?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

From some words on net I know that GCC is smart enough to decide whether to inline a function or not. The `inline` key word is just a hint: 
GCC may inline a *common function*, and may not inline an *inline function*.

But for this function in my project:

```
struct vb_pos{
    union{
        struct{
            int offset;
            int l;
        };
        unsigned long long g_offset;    
    };
};
static inline void vi_write_vtail_smart(struct vi *vi){
    struct vb_pos *vhead, *vtail, *cursor;
    vhead = &vi->v_head;                    
    vtail = &vi->v_tail;
    cursor = &vi->cursor;

    int curoff = vi->curr - vi->lines[vi->currl].buf;
    cursor->offset = curoff;    

    if(cursor->g_offset >= vhead->g_offset){
        *vtail = *cursor;
    }
    else{
        *vtail = *vhead;
        *vhead = *cursor;
    }
}
```

<sup>compiled with -O2.</sup>
I checked the assembly code, and knew this function was inlined as expected.
However, when I deleted its `inline` modifier, and recompiled, I found it was no loner inlined. Its function body appeared in final binary file:

```
0000000000000000 <vi_write_vtail_smart>:
       0:       48 63 47 14             movslq 0x14(%rdi),%rax
       4:       48 8b 17                mov    (%rdi),%rdx
       7:       48 8d 04 40             lea    (%rax,%rax,2),%rax
       b:       48 8d 04 c2             lea    (%rdx,%rax,8),%rax
       f:       48 8b 57 18             mov    0x18(%rdi),%rdx
      13:       48 2b 10                sub    (%rax),%rdx
      16:       89 57 10                mov    %edx,0x10(%rdi)
      19:       48 8b 47 10             mov    0x10(%rdi),%rax
      1d:       48 3b 47 38             cmp    0x38(%rdi),%rax
      21:       73 0d                   jae    30 <vi_write_vtail_smart+0x30>
      23:       48 8b 57 38             mov    0x38(%rdi),%rdx
      27:       48 89 47 38             mov    %rax,0x38(%rdi)
      2b:       48 89 57 40             mov    %rdx,0x40(%rdi)
      2f:       c3                      retq   
      30:       48 89 47 40             mov    %rax,0x40(%rdi)
      34:       c3                      retq
```

I want to know, since GCC is smart enough, why didn't it has its own decision? Why it performed inline when I specified, and no when I not?

Because he didn't find enough clue to make a strong decision? or, because he already got a decision, and his decision is: there is no much difference to inline or not, and since you ask me, i inline for you; otherwise, i leave it as a common function.

I want to know the real reason.
If it's the first case, i think we may need reconsider the viewpoint(very popular on the net) in this post beginning————At least, GCC is not as smart as they said, and the *inline* key word is not as useless as they said.

In the article end, I want to add more description for the context of the code snippet above:

1, I originally want `vi_write_vtail_smart()` to be inlined into function `A()` and `B()`, which are exported as library APIs and both will be often invoked by users.

2, `A()` and `B()` are within the same file with `vi_write_vtail_smart()`.

3, `vi_write_vtail_smart()` is only used in `A()` and `B()`, no where else.

4, the function body size of `A()` is about 450 bytes, `B()` is similar.

5, `A()`　and `B()` are basically plain machine code, no big loop or heavy computations involved, and only one subfunction is invoked, except `vi_write_vtail_smart()`.  That subfunction is in another file.

6, I did a small test, I added one line `return;` before *if(cursor->g_offset >= vhead->g_offset){*, (I wanted to see what happened when this function is small enough), namely:

```
...
int curoff = vi->curr - vi->lines[vi->currl].buf;
cursor->offset = curoff;    

return;
if(cursor->g_offset >= vhead->g_offset){
...
```

And compiled without `inline` modifier, and checked the assembly code————this time GCC inlined it and its function definition disappeared from final binary file.

7, My develop enviroment:
ubuntu-16.04 /64bit
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 
architecture: intel X86 Ivybridge Mobile

9,Compile flag( have to write here again, some people miss it when read)
-O2 -std=gnu99

Comment: Nice question, but you might make it even better by pointing out the exact GCC version, target OS and target architecture.

Comment: Note that the `inline` keyword still has an actual meaning which has nothing to do with whether the function gets inlined: With the keyword, the same function definition may appear once per translation unit and so can be in a header file.  Without the keyword, the function definition may only appear once per program, and so should not be in a header file.

Comment: So without the `inline` keyword, GCC *must* provide a definition as the named symbol, in case some other translation unit uses it.  But this does not prevent it from also inlining it in another function that calls it.

Comment: what's said above is true, but shouldn't apply to a `static` function (as in this example) which has visibility only in one single translation unit.

Comment: @aschepler See item **6** in the post end, i reduced the function size and recompiled and found its symbol name disappeared from the final target file( according to objdump). I think GCC is free to eliminate a static function totally  after inlined it within a translation unit.

Comment: Right, sorry, I forgot you also had `static`.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN It says `-O2` in the text, but granted, not in the most obvious place we would look.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to GCC documentation, GCC has an optimization setting called `-finline-functions`. This is actually the setting that makes GCC to use its heuristic inlining criteria on *all* functions, even if they are not declared `inline`. This setting is enabled at `-O3` optimization level. So, it you want to give GCC full freedom to apply its heuristics to all functions, you have to specify `-O3` at least (or specify `-finline-functions` explicitly).

Without `-finline-functions` GCC does not generally attempt to inline functions that are not declared `inline`, with some notable exceptions: a number of other inlining options might also lead to non-inline functions getting inlined. However, these options are targeted at very specific cases

- `-finline-functions-called-once` is enabled as early as `-O1`. Static functions called only once are inlined, even if they are not declared `inline`.
- `-finline-small-functions` is enabled at `-O2`. It triggers inlining if it results in reduction of code size, even if the function is not declared `inline`.

Your function apparently does not pass these specific inlining filters active at `-O2` level: it is relatively large and (apparently) called more than once. For this reason GCC does not consider it for inlining at `-O2`, unless you explicitly request it with `inline` keyword. Note, that explicit `inline` keyword is basically like `-finline-functions` setting turned on for that specific function only. It will make GCC to *consider* it for inlining, but does not guarantee inlining.

Again, if you want GCC to completely take over these decisions you need `-finline-functions` or `-O3`. The fact that explicit `inline` keyword triggers inlining at `-O2` means that GCC should decide to inline it at `-O3` regardless of whether `inline` is present there.

Comment: And there is `inline __attribute__((always_inline))`, which **forces** gcc to inline the function (even in non-optimized builds).

Comment: I recompiled with -O3 and checked, gcc indeed inlined it.

Comment: Note that there is also [`-fdump-ipa-inline`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9209268/194894) which will **show you the reason(s) why a function was inlined or not**.